# How to avoid overlapping last seaborn plot colors in new seaborn plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, visualization

I am trying to generate different colour bulk plots for data, but it doesn't use all the colours while saving the figure.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

total_ple = ['inferno', 'icefire_r', 'icefire', 'gray', 'gnuplot_r', 'gist_yarg_r', 'gist_stern', 'gist_heat_r', 'gist_heat', 'gist_gray', 'gist_earth', 'flare', 'crest_r', 'copper_r', 'coolwarm_r', 'cividis_r', 'cividis', 'YlGnBu_r', 'Spectral_r', 'Spectral', 'Set2', 'Set1', 
             'RdYlGn_r', 'RdYlBu_r', 'RdGy_r', 'RdBu_r', 'PuOr', 'PuBu_r', 'PuBuGn_r', 'PiYG', 'Paired', 'PRGn', 'Greys_r', 'GnBu_r', 'Dark2_r', 'Dark2', 'BrBG', 'Blues_r', 'Accent_r', 'viridis', 'tab10']


def bulk_plots(dfs_dict, ple="tab10", plot_name="default0"):

    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [20.0, 7.0]
    plt.rcParams.update(
        {
            "font.size": 22,
        }
    )

    sns.set_style("white")

    sns.set_context("talk", font_scale=0.8)
    for col_name, df_object in dfs_dict.items():
        sns.set_palette(ple)
        g = sns.distplot(df_object[col_name])

    sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)

    plt.tick_params(axis="x", which="major", labelsize=10)
    plt.savefig(f"{plot_name}.pdf", bbox_inches="tight", dpi=350)
```

dummy_data

```
df_data1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': np.random.randint(0,100,[10000])})
df_data2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_2': np.random.randint(0,100,[10000])})

df_data  = {'col_1': df_data1, 'col_2': df_data2}
```

Calling:

```
for k in total_ple:
    
    bulk_plots(df_data,
               ple = k,
               plot_name = f'default_{k}')
```

In the folder, I see only 2-3 colours being used, but if I  call `plt.show()` rather than `plt.savefig`, it shows all the colour plots in Jupiter's notebook.

How to save all color plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create multiple plots in a loop, it is advisable to specify in which figure and axis to draw the plot. In you case, you can re-define a new figure and a new axis in each loop with [**`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) and pass the axis to [**`seaborn.distplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html):

```
def bulk_plots(dfs_dict, ple="tab10", plot_name="default0"):

    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [20.0, 7.0]
    plt.rcParams.update(
        {
            "font.size": 22,
        }
    )

    sns.set_style("white")

    sns.set_context("talk", font_scale=0.8)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    for col_name, df_object in dfs_dict.items():
        sns.set_palette(ple)
        g = sns.distplot(df_object[col_name], ax = ax)

    sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)

    plt.tick_params(axis="x", which="major", labelsize=10)
    plt.savefig(f"folder/{plot_name}.pdf", bbox_inches="tight", dpi=350)
```